# Error connecting ConEmu cli to remote server

Tags: linux, cmd, putty

I've been trying to connect my remote CentOS server from a windows terminal application *ConEmu* using the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" username@<ipaddress>
```

And I keep getting the error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to run the command:

1. An absolute path configuration.

`"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" username@<ipaddress> -ssh`

2. A Relative path configuration.

For this, you need to set the environment variable. Where you store the absolute path value of the command.

```
plink.exe -shh username@<ipaddress>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is already a saved PuTTY session, then instead of supplying a hostname like so:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" username@<ipaddress> -ssh
```

or

```
plink.exe -shh username@<ipaddress>
```

The name of the saved session on PuTTY can be used instead:

```
plink.exe -ssh username@<savedsessionname>
```